# object from terrain domain

Tags: texturing, objects, import

It would be great if you can help me with this issue. I bought some mountain scans on terraindomain.com but the texturing tutorial is probably for maya users. I tried to make it in blender but the result is miles away from the official preview. Is here somebody who had the same issue? I tried to ask directly terraindomain admin, but without answer. I am uploading, how it should looks and how it looks on my screen haha (terrible :( so i just would like to know if the objects for maya has different approach of texturing, or its impossible to do with blender. Thanks :) enter image description here

[image]

Comment: The model doesn't look the same as on the reference picture. Make sure the model and the textures match or share the correct view point and better image of your material node set up.

Answer (score 0):

The model matches with prw, I plugged it like models from Blender Narket, color to base color, roughness to roughness, and displacement with normal, but also the wrapping is wrong, it doesn't works like models directly for Blender.

This one is for Maya, also the webpage tutorial is for Maya users.

[image]